# How to find Telegram channel by word in its message?

Tags: python, api, telegram, telethon

guys. Please tell me how to search for a channel in a Telegram by the text of the message?

That is what I mean: I have a word, let's say, "Batman", and I want to get a list of all messages in public channels where this word was mentioned. With channel name and message time.

How can I do it? Via Telegram? Via some libraries? I thought Telethon could help, but I cant figure out how (this - [telethon : How to search a keyword globally from telegram messages in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73621308/telethon-how-to-search-a-keyword-globally-from-telegram-messages-in-python) - does not help)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, you cannot globally search for messages from channels you have not joined. The best you can do is search all public channels by name using a word, using [`contacts.search`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/contacts/search.html):

```py
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types

with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    result = client(functions.contacts.SearchRequest(
        q='word',
        limit=100
    ))
    for channel in result.chats:
        print(channel)
```

In general, if something can't be done with official applications, it's unlikely third-party libraries like Telethon will be able to help, as they all use the same API when talking to Telegram in the end.

If you want to search messages across all dialogs (channels) you've joined, you can use [`client.iter_messages`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.messages.MessageMethods.iter_messages).